# Docker Compose with Java Spring Boot and Apache Kafka Bitnami (KRaft without Zookeeper)

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm trying to send some event to topic "helloworld" from Spring Boot Producer to Apache Kafka (KRaft without Zookeeper). I use following URL: `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/name/Chris`

As the result I get following error:

```
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:30.407Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:30.407Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:30.409Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:30.538Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
producer  |     acks = -1
producer  |     auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
producer  |     batch.size = 16384
producer  |     bootstrap.servers = [kafka:2181]
producer  |     buffer.memory = 33554432
producer  |     client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
producer  |     client.id = producer-1
producer  |     compression.type = none
producer  |     connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
producer  |     delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
producer  |     enable.idempotence = true
producer  |     interceptor.classes = []
producer  |     key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
producer  |     linger.ms = 0
producer  |     max.block.ms = 60000
producer  |     max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
producer  |     max.request.size = 1048576
producer  |     metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
producer  |     metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
producer  |     metric.reporters = []
producer  |     metrics.num.samples = 2
producer  |     metrics.recording.level = INFO
producer  |     metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
producer  |     partitioner.adaptive.partitioning.enable = true
producer  |     partitioner.availability.timeout.ms = 0
producer  |     partitioner.class = null
producer  |     partitioner.ignore.keys = false
producer  |     receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
producer  |     reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
producer  |     reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
producer  |     request.timeout.ms = 30000
producer  |     retries = 2147483647
producer  |     retry.backoff.ms = 100
producer  |     sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
producer  |     sasl.jaas.config = null
producer  |     sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
producer  |     sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
producer  |     sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
producer  |     sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
producer  |     sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
producer  |     sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
producer  |     sasl.login.class = null
producer  |     sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
producer  |     sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
producer  |     sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
producer  |     sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
producer  |     sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
producer  |     sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
producer  |     sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
producer  |     sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
producer  |     sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
producer  |     sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
producer  |     sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
producer  |     sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
producer  |     sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
producer  |     sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
producer  |     sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
producer  |     sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
producer  |     sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
producer  |     sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
producer  |     sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
producer  |     security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
producer  |     security.providers = null
producer  |     send.buffer.bytes = 131072
producer  |     socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
producer  |     socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
producer  |     ssl.cipher.suites = null
producer  |     ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
producer  |     ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
producer  |     ssl.engine.factory.class = null
producer  |     ssl.key.password = null
producer  |     ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
producer  |     ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
producer  |     ssl.keystore.key = null
producer  |     ssl.keystore.location = null
producer  |     ssl.keystore.password = null
producer  |     ssl.keystore.type = JKS
producer  |     ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
producer  |     ssl.provider = null
producer  |     ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
producer  |     ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
producer  |     ssl.truststore.certificates = null
producer  |     ssl.truststore.location = null
producer  |     ssl.truststore.password = null
producer  |     ssl.truststore.type = JKS
producer  |     transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
producer  |     transactional.id = null
producer  |     value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
producer  |
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:30.716Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:30.794Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.6.1
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:30.810Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 5e3c2b738d253ff5
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:30.811Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1705134750791
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:31.241Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='Hello World Chris' to topic helloworld:
producer  |
producer  | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support METADATA
producer  |
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:31.245Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Transiting to fatal error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support METADATA
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:32:31.251Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed] with root cause
producer  |
producer  | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support METADATA
producer  |
producer  | 2024-01-13T08:33:01.146Z  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Transiting to fatal error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support INIT_PRODUCER_ID
```

File **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:

  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.6
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka:9093
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=1
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qk
    networks:
      - network

  producer:
    image: producer
    container_name: producer
    build:
      context: ./springboot-kafka-producer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - network
    depends_on:
      - kafka
  
  # consumer:
  #   image: consumer
  #   container_name: consumer
  #   build:
  #     context: ./springboot-kafka-consumer
  #     dockerfile: Dockerfile
  #   ports:
  #     - "9090:9090"
  #   networks:
  #     - network
  #   depends_on:
  #     - kafka

networks:
  network:
    name: greeting-network
```

File **application.yml** for Producer:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
   kafka:
     producer:
        bootstrap-servers: kafka:9093
        key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

topic:
  name: helloworld
```

File **HelloWorldController.java**:

```
package com.example.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController { 
    
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
    
    @Value("${topic.name}")
    private String topicName;

    @Autowired
    public HelloWorldController(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/helloworld/name/{name}")
    public String helloWorld(@PathVariable(name = "name") String name) {
        
        String message = "Hello World " + name;
        kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);
        return "Done";
        
    }
    
}
```

Link to source code:
[Github](https://github.com/wisniewskikr/chrisblog-it-java-springboot/tree/main/arichitectures/event-driven/stream/kafka/kraft/springboot-kafka-bitnami-docker-compose)

I use Java in version 17, Spring Boot in version 3.2.1 and Kafka Bitnami (KRaft mode) in version 3.6. Any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using `bootstrap-servers` set to `kafka:9092`?

Comment: @zypherscript , thank you very much. It helped! So file **application.yml** for Producer should look like this: `server:
  port: 8080

spring:
   kafka:
     producer:
        bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092
        key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

topic:
  name: helloworld`

Comment: Link to working example you can fine here:
[Github Repository](https://github.com/wisniewskikr/chrisblog-it-java-springboot/tree/main/arichitectures/event-driven/stream/kafka/kraft/springboot-kafka-bitnami-docker-compose)

Answer (score 0):

Solution pointed by @zypherscript is to set `bootstrap-servers` to `kafka:9092`. So final **application.yml** file for Producer should look like this:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
   kafka:
     producer:
        bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092
        key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

topic:
  name: helloworld
```

Source code of working project you can find here:
[Github Repository](https://github.com/wisniewskikr/chrisblog-it-java-springboot/tree/main/arichitectures/event-driven/stream/kafka/kraft/springboot-kafka-bitnami-docker-compose)